# Jquery UI Sortable ConnectWith Not Working both ways

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

i'm using jQuery ui sortable for a web app and i have a strange problem.
Here is the code:

```
$(".internal_controlscontainer").each(
    function(index,el){
        $(this).sortable({connectWith:".internal_controlscontainer"})
    }
);
```

The problem is that when i try to grab an element from the first internal_controlscontainer and take it to the second internal_controlscontainer it doesn't work, but from the second to the first it works, why?

I read the jquery ui doc but i can't seem to find the problem

Roby

Comment: Please make a jsFiddle so we can help you better

Comment: @UmairP http://jsfiddle.net/HYvHq/5/

Comment: It has something to do with the width of #side. I increased it to 90%(same as head) and it works. If I give 40% width to both the divs, it still works. The problem is that the <li> with larger width is not getting in the smaller width div

Comment: @UmairP I cannot change the width of the li, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Sadly, This is the only way I know. #head li{
    width: 30%;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem as you.

It's really the width matters.

You cannot drag a long element to a short element.

Answer (score 3):

set tolerance to pointer.  By default the tolerance for sortable is to 50% of the object.  Meaning, 50% of what you're trying to place on the smaller container must fit inside it.  Setting the tolerance to pointer means only the mouse needs to hover over the drop location.

```
$('.column').sortable({
    connectWith:".column",
    tolerance:"pointer"
});
```

Comment: this was definitely my issue and this should be the answer these days